# UINavigationController in xib not displaying

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, interface-builder

I am trying to present a UInavigationController through an XIB by using PresentModalViewController. The Structure of my XIB is as follows:

```
UINavigationController
 -UIView
```

First Responder is wired to UIView. and UIVIew was dropped inside the UINavigationController

Now everytime the modal displays only the view is visible, and NavigationController is allways null.

it works ok if I initialise the UINavigationController programatically and only have a UIVIew in my xib like this:

```
var registerView = new RegisterView();
UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController(registerView);
registerView.Title="Register";
this.PresentModalViewController(navController,true);
```

It suggests that I am wiring the UINavigationController incorrectly in my XIB, is there any outlet that I should be wiring etc?

Also the problem is not related to the modal display with PresentModalViewController because I have tried to use that xib from the AppDelegate like this:

```
viewController = new RegisterView();
window.RootViewController = viewController;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the appdelegate just try things like this:

```
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        navcontroller = new UINavigationController ();
        navcontroller.PushViewController (new RegisterView(), false);
        window.RootViewController = navcontroller;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
```

need to add the navigation is rootviewcontroller with the homeview pushed on the view